# Print an EObject?

Tags: eclipse-emf

I am writing some eclipse emf code and would like to print the content of an EObject (not store it to disk).

Here is what I try:

```
  public static void print(EObject obj) {
    Resource eResource = obj.eResource();
    try {
      eResource.save(System.out, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

but that gives a NullPointerException. I have tried this instead:

```
  public static void print(EObject obj) {
    ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getProtocolToFactoryMap()
        .put("*", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
    Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("dummyfile.xml"));
    resource.getContents().add(obj);
    try {
      resource.save(System.out, null);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This works, but is it not possible to print to screen without specifying a dummy URI??

Answer (score 2):

*Updated to include EcoreUtil.copy()*

Check this code.

```
Resource res = new XMLResourceImpl ();
res.getContents().add(EcoreUtil.copy(obj));
try {
  resource.save(System.out, null);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

If that fails then yes you need a dummy URI

```
Resource res = new XMLResourceImpl (URI.createURI("dummyfile.xml"));
res.getContents().add(EcoreUtil.copy(obj));
try {
  resource.save(System.out, null);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Just need to put add a copy of my obj or else its gone after the print: res.getContents().add(EcoreUtil.copy(obj));

Comment: @tul I'll update the code. Keep in mind EMF is just a framework so all these objects are backed by implementations. I would guess there is a null implementation value which EcoreUtil replaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hm when I pass a copy:

```
Resource res = new XMLResourceImpl ();
res.getContents().add(ECoreUtil.copy(obj));
try {
  resource.save(System.out, null);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

some of the xmi attributes are not printed. But if I call the above method multiple times and DON't pass a copy I get a NullPointerException. I guess I am not understanding some basic EMF/Containment functionality here?

So my updated question is:

Is it possible to print a FULL EObject model without modifying the content if the model is used in the following code?